# Nuxt.js generate data fetched from remote api as a static website

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm creating a website using Nuxt.js - it contains blog posts, which I hold on my github repo and I query for them via github api.

How can I make this fetched data to be generated after running `nuxt generate` command as a static content on static website (no further api requests) ?

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following API:

https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-generate#routes

Additionally remember that when running `nuxt generate` all `asyncData` hooks will be called once. This is very useful if you want to build a static page with an external API-based CMS solution.